# How To Move The Windows Folder To A Different Drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, shortcuts, speed, junction

I have two small hard drives. However, i store all my files on the boot drive. This makes the boot drive very slow. I've read before that it's possible to move a folder to a different drive and make windows think it's still there by making a shortcut. I'd like to do this to the windows folder so that all the system programs run on my second drive and my personal programs run on the boot drive. Otherwise I would have to move all folders but windows to the other drive to achieve the same effect. Can I move the windows folder to a different drive and would this speed up my pc by seperating the load? I'm on windows 8.1.

Also, I've heard about moving the swap file to a different drive. Would this have much effect on the drive speed and would the swap file still work optimally?

Comment: No it's not possible (without reinstalling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mklink /J  creates a junction, but it is unwise to junction the Windows folder.  You could junction Program Files and/or Program Files (x86).  You can also junction your My Documents/My Music/ and etc.

You can also move the swap file.

Although it might be physically possible to junction Windows it could easily have unexpected consequences.  Programs not running correct, updates not installing, system crashing unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

These special directories are called symbolic links. It's possible in theory to move the Windows directory to another drive and replace it with a symbolic link, but one of many reasons the OS would not run from it is that support for symbolic links is part of the OS. The support would have to be implemented at a higher level for this to work.

Moreover, Windows will not allow you to move this directory, even if it doesn't contain a running OS, for example when booting from an install medium. Attempts to move the directory through an operating system that doesn't offer this protection will cause Windows to think the file system is corrupt.

The only practical way to move this directory is to reinstall Windows.